# WPF Bind A Listbox To 2 Table With Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listbox

Is it possible to have a listbox binded to more than one table and insert or delete rows from tables just by check and uncheck a checkbox in listbox?

َActually I want a listbox with all available "Products" followed by a checkbox for a Specific "Sale". and checking a "Product" checkbox should insert a row in "SaleItem" table and unchecking Make a deletion form "SaleItem" table.

```
public class Sale
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public String CustomerName { set; get; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public String ProductName { set; get; }
}

public class SaleItem
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public int SaleID { set; get; }
    public int ProductID { set; get; }
}
```

for clarity classes are not complete.

Comment: do you know about implementing INotifyProperyChanged? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40623975/3225  That's a good place to start, but all of what you describe is certainly possible.

Comment: @kenny i know but it's hard, because all linq db models and relations are made by Designer and i afraid about manual change in designer generated codes.

Comment: Typically you map your data models to your view models which implement INotifyPropertyChanged back and forth. Probably too advanced for you today, but AutoMapper open source library can be helpful for that. http://automapper.org/

Comment: @kenny thanks for suggestion, I'll Check it.